# Aquatic forest insect identification

Tags: species-identification, species-distribution, freshwater-biology

I found it in the forest but I've never seen anything like it so I took it home to see what it is. Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: There are few things a species identification [query](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) must fulfill; locale, dimensions of the species and clear picture(s) (ideally from as many angles possible - so that all parts of the specimen are conspicuous to the one trying to ID your specimen).

Answer (score 2):

This is a caddisfly larvae (*Trichoptera*). They live in streams and other water that are rich in oxygen. 
They protect themselves by building there own 'house', with whatever is available, e.g. plant or wood fragments, gravel or even snail shells (see picture below)

[image]
Picture from [Dutch wiki](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schietmotten)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddisfly

[image]

Id to species level probably requires microscopic work.